# What is in average the text percentage of a pdf/word document?

Tags: pdf, solr, lucene

The thing is I have more than `1TB` of documents that needs to be indexed with solr, most of this amount is pdf/word, I would say `80%` which turns to be `800GB` of data that needs to be indexed but I do believe that I don't need a disc with `800GB` to store the index. So, my question is, what is in average the text percentage of a pdf/word document? With that information I can estimate the disk size.

Comment: The index size will depend greatly on whether you want to store the text in the index or not. You normally store the text in the index if you want to retrieve it from the index (e.g. to show context snippets in your results).

Answer (score 0):

To index PDFs/MSWords, Solr uses Apache Tika under the covers. If you are planning to do such heavy indexing, you may actually want to use Tika in a standalone client and send only the extracted portion to Solr. That would be both faster and of less impact on Solr itself, as the extraction is happening out of its process.

Which means as a first version of the program, you can write something that uses Tika to read documents and just calculate the extract size you get. Without storing it. Run that against the representative part of your source documents and you should get your real percentages.

Answer (score 0):

Without having access to a representative set of your files it is next to impossible to estimate which percentage of a file's size represents text.

In general, if there are lots of images or extensive graphical non-text content the percentage will often be just a few percent of the file's size.

Now, in order to get an idea about your files I can suggest two approaches:

- use Adobe Acrobat Pro, do "Save as..." for a couple of your PDF files, in the "Save as..." dialog set the option "Optimized PDF", then go to "Settings..." and in the settings dialog click on "Audit space usage...." - you will get a dialog that indicated sizes for several types of data in the PDF, e.g. images, overhead, metadata, etc. While it does not list text as such, the relative contribution of "Content Streams" will be an excellent indicator of your text size (while content streams can draw a lot of different stuff, and not just text, they are also typically Flate [a filter similar to ZIP compression] compressed)
- use any decent PDF viewer of your liking, select all the text in it and save it to a plain text file; depending on what tools you use you might be able to automate this on the command line or by writing a small program, e.g. with PDFBox

Disclaimer: I am not really in a position to aid with Word files, but extracting just the raw text from Word should give you similarly indicative information.